# How to clear an entire php web page after clicking a button?

Tags: php

I am outputting a Quiz question in a web browser. I want to select the answer and click a "Next" Button to move over to the next question which should be displayed in the same page. I have used javascript to print all questions on the same page. However, when I click next the next question gets printed below the previous one.

Is there a way in which I can clear the page so that the second question is the only one that is displayed on the page?

I am using a  tag to point to the next question. For example,

**IN PAGE test.php********

```
<form id="q1_id" action="testcalc.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>
<?php
echo $question;
?>
</legend>
<input type="radio" name="definition1" value="<?php echo $answer1; ?>"><?php echo $answer1; ?><br>
<input type="radio" name="definition1" value="<?php echo $answer2; ?>"><?php echo $answer2; ?><br>
<input type="radio" name="definition1" value="<?php echo $answer3; ?>"><?php echo $answer3; ?><br>
</fieldset>
<button id="b1_id">Next</button>
</form>
```

After this page is executed, I want to be able to print only the next question which is present in "testcalc.php" in the url "test.php". I am being able to do this using javascript, but both questions are displayed under the url "test.php".

Comment: How did you load the questions in the first place? Try getting the id of the form and set it's HTML property to 'empty'.

Comment: You left out all the important parts of your code, how do you expect a proper answer?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose you can change your action value from `action="testcalc.php"` to something like `action="testcalc.php?part=2"` now, the first time you submit or click the button, the page will be the same, but still will add a query string of `part=2` now, this will help you to manipulate the page more, as you can use the `$_GET` method to check if you should execute the second part of the question like:

```
if(!$_GET['part'] && empty($_GET['part'])) {

// show **1st part** of the questions

}else if(isset($_GET['part']) && $_GET['part']==2){

// show **2nd part** of the questions
}
```

Now - First time you open the page, or if you did not click any button, the 1st script will run, if you press the button however, the second part will run

Answer (score 0):

The usual way this sort of thing is done is by sending values using either post/get to the page with the next question and using them to create hidden input tags, and the next time passing these hidden input tags as well to the next page, or you could do what Simon said.

If you want people to be able to migrate between the questions , this would be more efficient.

You add put each question on a different page and add this code to each of them:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
// set some validation for the type for keys you want
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"{$key}\" value=\"{$value}\" />\n";
}
```

The only other thing to be done is to set the action of your form using some javascript 
(to decide the next page). This way the user could migrate to all the questions instead of just the next one.